# Increase the speed of the snake when food is eaten

Tags: python

I am coding a basic snake game using python and wish to increase the snake's speed every time a piece of food is eaten.
I attempted to add snake_speed + 5 whenever the food is eaten by adding it to the if statement affecting the length of the snake.

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

#colors

white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)
orange = (218,103,60)
pink = (255, 105, 180)

#window geometry 
dis_width = 700
dis_height = 600

#window
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))

#title
pygame.display.set_caption('Wizzys Pill Bottle')

#clock variable 
 clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

This is where snake_speed is defined.

```
#snake_stuff 
snake_block = 10

snake_speed = 15
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)


def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Adderall eaten: " + str(score), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])

def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])

def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])


def gameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False

    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    while not game_over:
            while game_close == True:
        
            dis.fill(blue)
            message("OVERDOSED. For stomach pump press C", red)
            Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event. Type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event. Key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event. Key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event. Type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event. Type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event. Key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event. Key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event. Key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event. Key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0

        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        dis.fill(orange)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, pink, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]

        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True
    

        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
    


        pygame.display.update()

        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
            snake_speed + 5

         
        clock. Tick(snake_speed)
        pygame.quit()
        quit()


    gameLoop()
```

After running the code, I am unable to see any change.

Answer (score 0):

After fixed few typo and indentation errors as shown below, it runs!

Then to increase speed: `snake_speed = snake_speed + 5`

Also need to move the snake_speed variable inside the gameLoop() to avoid the `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'snake_speed' referenced before assignment"` error

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

#colors

white = (255, 255, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 102)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (213, 50, 80)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (50, 153, 213)
orange = (218,103,60)
pink = (255, 105, 180)

#window geometry 
dis_width = 700
dis_height = 600

#window
dis_width = 700
dis_height = 600

#window
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))

#title
pygame.display.set_caption('Wizzys Pill Bottle')

#clock variable 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
 
 #snake_stuff 
snake_block = 10

font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("bahnschrift", 25)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 35)

def Your_score(score):
    value = score_font.render("Adderall eaten: " + str(score), True, yellow)
    dis.blit(value, [0, 0])

def our_snake(snake_block, snake_list):
    for x in snake_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, black, [x[0], x[1], snake_block, snake_block])

def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    dis.blit(mesg, [dis_width / 6, dis_height / 3])

def gameLoop():
    game_over = False
    game_close = False

    x1 = dis_width / 2
    y1 = dis_height / 2

    x1_change = 0
    y1_change = 0

    snake_List = []
    Length_of_snake = 1

    foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
    foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0

    snake_speed = 15 #move the variable inside the gameLoop

    while not game_over:
        while game_close == True:
            dis.fill(blue)
            message("OVERDOSED. For stomach pump press C", red)
            Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
            pygame.display.update()
    
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x1_change = -snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x1_change = snake_block
                    y1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -snake_block
                    x1_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = snake_block
                    x1_change = 0

        if x1 >= dis_width or x1 < 0 or y1 >= dis_height or y1 < 0:
            game_close = True
        x1 += x1_change
        y1 += y1_change
        dis.fill(orange)
        pygame.draw.rect(dis, pink, [foodx, foody, snake_block, snake_block])
        snake_Head = []
        snake_Head.append(x1)
        snake_Head.append(y1)
        snake_List.append(snake_Head)
        if len(snake_List) > Length_of_snake:
            del snake_List[0]

        for x in snake_List[:-1]:
            if x == snake_Head:
                game_close = True
    

        our_snake(snake_block, snake_List)
        Your_score(Length_of_snake - 1)
    
        pygame.display.update()

        if x1 == foodx and y1 == foody:
            foodx = round(random.randrange(0, dis_width - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            foody = round(random.randrange(0, dis_height - snake_block) / 10.0) * 10.0
            Length_of_snake += 1
            snake_speed = snake_speed + 5 #fixed the assignment

        clock.tick(snake_speed)
        
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```